# SQL Server 2008 r2: What events/queries hit tempdb

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

We had a slowdown on a db server this morning. Checking the logs, the only thing that happened during the 2-minute slowdown worth noting was an object being created and deleted in tempdb over the span of about 3ms. I know that temporary tables and table variables would do this, but as far as I can tell none were used. Are there any other actions (e.g. nested selects) which might create a temporary table?

P.S. We've already figured out that it was most likely a log expansion that caused the slowdown, and the hit to tempdb was unrelated. I just wanted to ask for academic purposes and because I just cannot figure out what caused tempdb to be used.

Comment: There's a good rundown here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345368.aspx

Comment: Lots of things can use tempdb in addition to temp tables and table variables - CTEs, sorts, joins, spools, cursors, snapshot isolation, service broker, index maintenance... what else did you observe about the "object" that was created, and other than the fact that it happened in your 2-minute window, what leads you to believe it is anything but a coincidence?

Comment: +1 @AaronBertrand - the real question is how does he know it's tempdb related at all

Answer (score 3):

To summarize Tempdb is used to store 3 types of objects:

1. **user objects**

   - local temporary table (seen by one session)
   - global temporary table (seen by all sessions)
   - Table variables
2. **internal objects** used temporarily by SQL server during Query processing : operations such as sort , join, hash and cursors all require space in tempdb. see the sys.dm_db_session_space_usage DMV.
3. the **version store** : 
   The following features make use of the version store:

   - Triggers
   - Snapshot isolation or Read-Commited Snapshot isolation
   - Online index operations
   - Multiple Active Result Sets (MARS)

Please note that using the sys.dm_tran_version_store can be ressource intensive.

May I suggest that you check [Troubleshooting insufficient disk space in tempdb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176029.aspx) for a few examples of how to use the DMV.